# Eclipse JFace editor with JavaScript support

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface, dot.js

I'm developing Eclipse editor with SWT/JFace for doT.js template engine. I have done tags highlighting, content assist with doT.js global variables and tags. But I'm new at Eclipse plugin development and I have a probleem.

Problem is that inside doT.js tags I need JavaScript syntacs. Is it possible to use already existing editors/ plugins (like Aptana plugin) or add JS syntacs some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Aptana plugin to get JavaScript and HTML syntax support for my editor. WTP seemed to complicated for that.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP) contains a Javascript editor.

You can install this using 'Help > Install New Software...' Choose you main Eclipse site in the 'Work with' field (`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna` for Luna).

Choose 'Javascript Development Tools' in the 'Web, XML, Java EE...' section.

Comment: This isn't actually answer that really helps. I think I use WTP SDK to get that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of the tern.java.

If you need powerfull completion, hyperlink, hover, validation, for JavaScript, I suggest you that you try tern.java. You can use it with a simple SWT Text:

[image]

See this sample at [tern.eclipse.swt.samples](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/tree/master/eclipse/tern.eclipse.swt.samples)

Comment: I already used Aptana plugin for JavaScript and HTML syntax support. WTP seemed too complicated for that.

Comment: tern.java can be used without WTP with a simple SWT Text.

Comment: I have already used Aptana and I think I rewrite that part again in my editor. But still, it is good thing to know.

Comment: Pay attention, it's just for completion, validation, hyperlink, hover not for syntax coloration.